# Computation of an integral using residue theorem.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

> Using residue theorem compute the following integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {e^{\frac {x} {2}}} {1 + e^x}\ dx.$$

I have tried to proceed by the method of substitution by taking $y = e^{\frac {x} {2}}.$ Then $dy = \frac {1} {2} e^{\frac {x} {2}}\ dx$ i.e. $e^{\frac {x} {2}}\ dx = 2\ dy.$ Then the limit of integration becomes $0$ to $\infty.$ So by this substitution the integral becomes $$2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {dy} {1 + y^2} = 2 \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \arctan x = \pi.$$

By residue theorem how to deal with the same integral? Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can rewrite the integral in the form $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {1} {e^{x/2} + e^{-x/2}}dx=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {dt} {\cosh(t)}$ and to use the rectangular contour $(-R)\to R\to R+i\to(-R)+i\to (-R)$, where $R\to\infty$. You will have to evaluate the residue at one simple pole inside the contour (at $x=i/2$)

Comment: @Svyatoslav Shouldn't the pole be at $x=i \pi /2$. Because $\cosh(i\pi/2)=0$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a typo - the pole is at $x=\pi i/2$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting from your result, we have that
$$2\int_{[0,\infty)}\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{1+z^2}dz$$
Consider the half-disk of radius $R$, which we call $C_R$; by the residue theorem
$$\int_{C_R}\frac{1}{1+z^2}dz=2\pi i\, \textrm{Res}\bigg(\frac{1}{1+z^2},i\bigg)$$
$$\textrm{Res}\bigg(\frac{1}{1+z^2},i\bigg)=\lim_{z \to i}(z-i)\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)}=-\frac{1}{2}i$$
$$\int_{C_R}\frac{1}{1+z^2}dz=\pi$$
We may want to estimate the integral on the semicircle $\Gamma_R$.
$$\bigg|\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{1}{1+z^2}dz\bigg|\leq \pi R \max_{z \in \Gamma_R}\bigg|\frac{1}{1+z^2}\bigg|$$
$$\bigg|\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{1}{1+z^2}dz\bigg|\leq \pi R \frac{1}{R^2-1}\stackrel{R \to \infty}{\rightarrow} 0$$
Since
$$\int_{[-R,R]}\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy=\int_{C_R}\frac{1}{1+z^2}dz-\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{1}{1+z^2}dz$$
in the limit we obtain the desired result.

Comment: Do you mean that $C_R = [-R,R] * \Gamma_R,$ where $*$ is the concatenation of paths and $\Gamma_R (t) : = Re^{it},$ where $0 \leq t \leq \pi\ $?

Comment: @AntonioClaire yes

Answer (score 3):

The function has poles at

$$e^z = -1 \implies z = i\pi + i2\pi k \hspace{12 pt} k\in\Bbb{Z}$$

So choose $C$ to be rectangle with corners $z=\pm R, \pm R + 2\pi i $ and integrate

$$\int_{C_R}f(z)\:dz = \int_{-R}^R f(x)\:dx + \int_0^{2\pi}f(R+iy)\:idy + \int_R^{-R}f(x+2\pi i)\:dx + \int_{2\pi}^0f(-R+iy)\:idy$$

$$=2\pi i \sum_z \operatorname{Res}_z(f) = 2\pi i\operatorname{Res}_{i\pi}(f)$$

$f(x+2\pi i) = -f(x)$, so in the limit the two long sides add and the short sides vanish

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R}f(z)\:dz = 2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\:dx = 2\pi i\lim_{z\to i\pi}\frac{(z-i\pi)e^{\frac{z}{2}}}{1+e^z} = 2\pi i \cdot -i = 2\pi$$

Thus we have

$$\implies \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\:dx = \pi$$

Answer (score 2):

alternatively:
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb R}\frac{e^{x/2}}{1+e^{x}}dx=\int\limits_{\mathbb R}\frac{dx}{e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}}$$
making the substitution $u=x/2\Rightarrow dx=2du$ we get:
$$2\int\limits_{\mathbb R}\frac{du}{e^u+e^{-u}}=\int\limits_{\mathbb R}\operatorname{sech}(u)\,du=\pi$$

---

Or as others have said make the substitution $u=e^{x/2}$ and you will get something in terms of $\arctan$

Comment: Whilst this isn't using residue theorem I thought it would be interesting to show